# D3 append is not a function when using with VueJS and Vuex

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vue.js

I have a html 'div' and I am trying to append another div to it by the following :

```
var myDiv = d3.select("#container")    
myDiv.append("div")
```

And I get the following error :

> myDiv .append is not a function

Any ideas ? I am using Vuex, so I instantiated the variable in the store and trying to set it to the d3 select.

I have put together a codepen that's similar to what I have : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMBGmd?editors=1010

```
    const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    networkVariables: {
      node: "",
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    },
    container: ""
  },
  getters: {},
  mutations: {}
});

console.log("line 33");
console.log(store);

var networkVariables = store.state.networkVariables;
var container = store.state.container;
container = d3.select("#container");

console.log(networkVariables);

networkVariables.node = container
  .selectAll(".node")
  .data(networkVariables.data);

console.log(networkVariables.node);

networkVariables.nodeEnter = networkVariables.node.append("div");
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Can you create a running snippet, or reproduce the issue using a site like JSFiddle?

Comment: Most likely there is no tag with id `divId`. the selection is empty or undefined. Use the debugger to see what myDiv is?

Comment: @rioV8 Nope, that would not give the mentioned error.

Comment: the thing is, I have this working else where in my code. Find it difficult to reproduce. Probably a data issue, I have checked if the element is there and it is. I understand the question is vague, and annoying that i have no example, I'm just wondering if someone has hit the same thing

Comment: One thing to note, I am using VueJs, webpack and Babel, perhaps there is an inconsistency between these ?

Comment: By any chance does the div id value have any non-alpha characters in it? I've had issues with that before -- but it's likely that you would not get the error your are showing it this was the problem...

Comment: No, the id which this happens is camel case

Comment: oh, forgot to mention, i am using Vuex to store these variables too. So i am accessing and setting the state

Comment: @thatOneGuy That's probably a conflict between D3 and Vue (not Babel). I added the Vue tag... please try to create an [MCVE] with the Vue part.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado i think I have been able to put something similar together https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMBGmd?editors=1010

Comment: The code in the linked codepen no longer matches your question.  Further, if I make it match seems to work find.  Voting to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

In your latest codepen, the error you mentioned is coming from the last line, where you are trying to append to the `networkVariable.node` directly -- without using the enter selection.

It seems to work for me when I change the last line to be:

```
networkVariables.nodeEnter = networkVariables.node.enter();
networkVariables.nodeEnter.append("div");
```

Comment: Although it fixes the error, it is not equivalent to OP's code. Generally, there is nothing wrong with calling `.append()` on the update selection.

Comment: True, but in this case, the networkVariables "properties" called `node` and `data` are actually getter/setter functions in the Vue framework (it seems) -- which is why the d3 `append` method is not available. And since his code appears to be starting with an empty page and building the DOM elements from the data, why not use the `enter()` selection?

Comment: `networkVariables.node` is the return of a `.data(...)` call. It is not the result of a `.select(...)`. It is the `exit()` group that is an empty "list".

Answer (score 0):

Here `networkVariables.nodeEnter = networkVariables.node.append("div");`, there is no `append()` in `networkVariables.node` object. I tried replacing `networkVariables.node.append()` with `networkVariables.node[0].parentNode.append("div")`, this seems to work in the snippet. can you try with this change.

Answer (score -1):

The line in the codepen with the error is like @SteveR noticed the last line.

It is **not** the result of a `d3.select()` but a `d3.selectAll(..).data(...)`. The array contains 5 `empty` placeholders and two fields. These are `enter` and `exit`, both functions. To convert this to a "selection" result you have to call one of these functions first before you can `append()`.

But in the original question there should be no problem appending if the tag with the given id exists.

The codepen is not similar to the original question/example.